# Find the euclidean distance between two Pandas dataframes with different number on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the euclidean distance between two Pandas dataframes with different number on rows.

I have 2 measures of position (x and y) in two different pandas dataframes. The two sensors dont have the same sampling frequency. And I want to know the difference between the 2 measured positions.

Here is one piece of my data, x and y are in meters.
[image: Graph]

My pandas dataframes are formatted like this :
[image: dataset description]

At the end I should get a dataframe of the euclidean distances :

[image]

I have been trying several hours and I cant find a good way to do it, do you have any hint? thanks !

Comment: What would the expected output look like?

Comment: A dataframe with one column being the perpendicular euclidean distance between each blue dot and the red line